# having a problem waiting for ctest_submit

Tags: cmake, ctest

I'm having a problem when using `ctest_submit()` to submit my build results for the dashboard server. I'm trying to build my project using `ctest_build()` and then i submit the results using `ctest_submit()`. However, i don't want to wait for `ctest_submit()` to finish submitting the results before continue executing the rest of the `cmake` script. Instead, i want to trigger the submission and continue executing the script without waiting for the `cmake_submit()` to finish. Is there anyway i can do this ?